# Can't open excel source in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a C# program that download an excel file from Email then a SSIS insert from Excel to DB to read and insert the data that was just downloaded. The C# download the file and then the SSIS excel source doesn't recognize the file and I can't preview it, I get the following error :
[SSIS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqqeD.png)

If I manually open the file then go back to SSIS excel source I can preview the file and it works fine, it seems like the file is somehow locked, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you can open the file manually outside of SSIS and then the Excel connection manager can "see" the file makes me think your C# isn't saving the file correctly.

Comment: there are different connection strings based on xls or xlsx

Comment: @digital.aaron I am using fileAttachment.Load("path")  to save the file, would this be the problem ?

Comment: @KeithL yap, and I am using the xls

Comment: are you reading an email or downloading from a URL?

Comment: @KeithL I am downloading it from an email attachment to a local folder then reading it from there.

Comment: You probably need to write the file to disk after you load it. Check out the code at the bottom of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: @digital.aaron I am usign Microsft code for "Get attachments from an email by using the EWS Managed API" from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange, since I am downloading an excel attachment from an email(file attachment)

Comment: When you call `Load("path")`, are you including the file name in `"path"`?

Comment: @digital.aaron, yes I have the file name, I did find a way to do this, please look at my answer below in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by creating another C# program that opens the excel file once its done downloading and I added it to the SSIS flow, so now the file will get downloaded -> open and closed -> then loaded to the excel source.